# repeat number of times based on user input

Tags: applescript

Not sure. Basically I want the user to click the dialogue. If the NPC has 250, repeat 25 times. Whatever the NPC has repeat / 10 times.

It keeps giving me the error that rtimes is undefined, and rtimes should be defined in the if statements

Code:

```
(choose from list {"50", "100", "200", "250"} ¬
with prompt "How many does the NPC have?")
set list_answer to result
set tom to result
set rtimes to (tom / 10)

if tom is equal to 50 then
    set rtimes to 5
end if

if tom is equal to 100 then
    set rtimes to 10
end if

if tom is equal to 200 then
    set rtimes to 20
end if

if tom is equal to 250 then
    set rtimes to 25
end if

display dialog tom
display dialog rtimes
```

Answer (score 2):

I got no error from your script, but here is a more concise way to write what you're wanting to accomplish:

```
set tom to (choose from list {"50", "100", "200", "250"} ¬
    with prompt "How many does the NPC have?")
set rtimes to (tom / 10) as integer
display dialog "tom: " & tom & return & "rtimes: " & rtimes
```